# Zebra IMZ Print Large Text from IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

have a large text to print from ios
1.i use adobe flex to print ( i have made something called adobe native extension to connect and print to imz320 on ios)
2.it connects fine
3.if i print a small text it works file
now if i print a large text the blue light on the printer blinks but nothing happens
if i put the same text and try to print the text using zebra setup utilities by putting it in a file its prints well
the same text i use it to print from Android and its prints fine without any problems

See code below
i thing the problem is something with IOS bluetooth
i have traced the text that recived on the ios and what is sent to the printer its the same as the attached file
does anyone has an idea

```
^XA^LRN^CI0^XZ ^XA^MNN^LL1290^XZ^XA^JUS^XZ  ^XA^CWZ,E:TT0003M_.FNT^FS^XZ ^XA ^PA1,1,1,1^FS ^FX Enables Advanced Text ^FS ^FO200145^CI28^AZN,30,40^FD الوقت   ^FS ^FO5,145^CI28^AZN,30,40^FD التاريخ  ^FS ^FO200220^CI28^AZN,30,40^FD 16:51:01 ^FS ^FO5,220^CI28^AZN,30,40^FD 17/01/2017 ^FS ^FO150,295^CI28^AZN,60,30^FD  شركة سنقرط للمنتوجات الغذائية ^FS ^FO170,370^CI28^AZN,60,40^FD  Sami ^FS ^FO100,445^CI28^AZN,60,40^FD  مشتغل مرخص رقم:562402552 ^FS ^FO170,520^CI28^AZN,60,40^FD  Sami ^FS ^FO170,595^CI28^AZN,60,40^FD رقم الفاتورة :**** ^FS ^FO10,670^CI28^AZN,60,25^FD  المطلوب من  Sami   ^FS ^FO05,705^CI28^AZN,30,30^FD ______________________________________ ^FS ^FO05,740^CI28^AZN,30,30^FD  التعبئة ^FS ^FO90,740^CI28^AZN,30,30^FD  سعر ^FS ^FO175,740^CI28^AZN,30,30^FD الكمية ^FS ^FO410,740^CI28^AZN,30,30^FD البيان ^FS ^FO490,740^CI28^AZN,30,30^FD المبلغ ^FS ^FO05,775^CI28^AZN,30,30^FD ______________________________________ ^FS ^FO05,810^CI28^AZN,30,30^FD ______________________________________ ^FS ^FO05,880^CI28^AZN,30,30^FD ______________________________________ ^FS ^FO340,915^CI28^AZN,30,30^FD المجموع :0.00 ^FS ^FO1500,950^CI28^AZN,30,30^FD المجموع الكلي يشمل قيمة تاضريبة المضافة ^FS^FS ^XZ
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I would suggest you check the [Multiplatform SDK](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/link-os-sdk.html) from Zebra.
2. Check your zpl Text using [this online viewer](http://labelary.com/viewer.html). The Text width seems to be wrong.

EDIT:
Maybe there are some differences between android and ios:
Anyway your zpl string width looks too big.

[image]

Comment: i think nothing wrong couse the same string is working on android without any errors!!!

Comment: the problem is i see the bluetooth ligh blinks when i connect and send the text bit nothing is printed even i took the same text from the viwer site